# how display small portion of text from big text flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget, flutter-text, flutter-textinputfield

### Acutal

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris non mauris nulla. Nam euismod condimentum erat, tempor efficitur quam. Aliquam commodo pretium libero vel interdum. Quisque suscipit a massa suscipit auctor. Maecenas faucibus mattis interdum. Duis lacinia turpis at tortor aliquet, sit amet consequat nibh molestie. Vestibulum sit amet placerat sapien. Cras efficitur orci massa, non mattis nunc laoreet porta. Maecenas purus lacus, consectetur ac lorem et, pulvinar venenatis neque. Quisque hendrerit sagittis rutrum. Sed et suscipit elit. Donec in lectus in nisi vestibulum venenatis at eu nisi. Phasellus diam est, varius ac odio ac, facilisis hendrerit sapien.

### Expected

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris non mauris nulla. Nam euismod condimentum erat, tempor efficitur quam. Aliquam commodo pretium libero vel interdum. Quisque suscipit a massa suscipit auctor. Maecenas faucibus mattis interdum. Duis lacinia turpis at tortor aliquet, sit amet consequat nibh molestie. Vestibulum sit amet placerat sapien. Cras...

### Note

- No readmore feature

Comment: You can use readmore package.
https://pub.dev/packages/readmore

Answer (score 1):

You can use the overflow property to get this effect

```
Expanded(
    child: Text(
      "Any Large Text",
      maxLines: 5,
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
   ),
);
```

**Make sure to wrap Text widget with Expanded.**

You can also try other properties like **minLines** or other forms of overflow like **TextOverflow.fade** or **TextOverflow.clip.**

Comment: worked only need *maxLines: 5* for 5 lines

Comment: Ok, I have updated it and you can change it for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `maxLines` in combination with `overflow` attributes from [`Text`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html) widget.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text(
          'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris non mauris nulla. Nam euismod condimentum erat, tempor efficitur quam. Aliquam commodo pretium libero vel interdum. Quisque suscipit a massa suscipit auctor. Maecenas faucibus mattis interdum. Duis lacinia turpis at tortor aliquet, sit amet consequat nibh molestie. Vestibulum sit amet placerat sapien. Cras efficitur orci massa, non mattis nunc laoreet porta. Maecenas purus lacus, consectetur ac lorem et, pulvinar venenatis neque. Quisque hendrerit sagittis rutrum. Sed et suscipit elit. Donec in lectus in nisi vestibulum venenatis at eu nisi. Phasellus diam est, varius ac odio ac, facilisis hendrerit sapien.',
          maxLines: 6,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris non mauris nulla. Nam euismod condimentum erat, tempor efficitur quam. Aliquam commodo pretium libero vel interdum. Quisque suscipit a massa suscipit auctor. Maecenas faucibus mattis interdum. Duis lacinia turpis at tortor aliquet, sit amet consequat nibh molestie. Vestibulum sit amet placerat sapien. Cras efficitur orci massa, non mattis nunc laoreet porta. Maecenas purus lacus, consectetur ac lorem et, pulvinar venenatis neque. Quisque hendrerit sagittis rutrum. Sed et suscipit elit. Donec in lectus in nisi vestibulum venenatis at eu nisi. Phasellus diam est, varius ac odio ac, facilisis hendrerit sapien.';
  
  bool readMore = false;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan( //change 200 to required length
  text : text.length>200 && readMore ? text : text.substring(0,200),
    children: <TextSpan>[
      text.length > 200 ?
      TextSpan(text: readMore?
               ' Show Less' : '...Read More...', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue,),
              recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()..onTap = () {
      setState((){
        readMore = !readMore;
      });
    },
              ) :null,
    ]
  ), 
      );
  }
```

[Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/flutter) Screenshots

[image]
[image]